# How to have date on YYYY-MM with function extract()

Tags: sql, date, format, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I try to have all value only if the month is finished.  I did it for the moment :

```
select
extract(month from mois_entre ) as mois_finis 
 from   table1
where  extract(year from mois_entre ) = extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) and
extract(month from mois_entre ) < extract(month from CURRENT_DATE()) or extract(year from mois_entre ) < extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) 
and to_char(mois_entre , 'yyyy/mm/dd') between  '2021/01/01'  and '2021/07/16'
```

It works perfectly but my problem is that I have my results like this :

```
mois_finis
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

So "1" means january,  2 means "February" ect. and I don't have 7 because july is not finished yet.

But now my aim is to have :

```
mois_finis

january-2021
February-2021
...
...
June-2021
```

OR  to have

```
01-2021  or 2021-01
..
...
..
06-2021  or 2021-06
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using ( one of Oracle, SQL Server, MySQL, Postgres, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use TO_VARCHAR to extract some parts of the date instead of using EXTRACT:

```
with table1 as (
select '2021-01-01'::date mois_entre )
select
TO_VARCHAR(mois_entre,'MM-YYYY' ) as mois_finis,
TO_VARCHAR(mois_entre,'MMMM-YYYY' ) as mois_finis_alternative
from   table1
where  extract(year from mois_entre ) = extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) and
extract(month from mois_entre ) < extract(month from CURRENT_DATE()) or extract(year from mois_entre ) < extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) 
and to_char(mois_entre , 'yyyy/mm/dd') between  '2021/01/01'  and '2021/07/16' ;


+------------+------------------------+
| MOIS_FINIS | MOIS_FINIS_ALTERNATIVE |
+------------+------------------------+
| 01-2021    | January-2021           |
+------------+------------------------+
```

It's also possible to extract year and month and combine them but it would be extra effort:

```
with table1 as (
select '2021-01-01'::date mois_entre )
select
extract(year from mois_entre ) || '-' || ltrim(to_varchar(extract(month from mois_entre ), '00' )) as mois_finis
from   table1
where  extract(year from mois_entre ) = extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) and
extract(month from mois_entre ) < extract(month from CURRENT_DATE()) or extract(year from mois_entre ) < extract(year from CURRENT_DATE()) 
and to_char(mois_entre , 'yyyy/mm/dd') between  '2021/01/01'  and '2021/07/16' ;
```